# SQL Server Sum by 5 days periods

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum

I would appreciate some help on this. I have this table:

```
RECHARGES
___________
DATE_TIME               CLIENT          RECHARGED_MONEY
2011-01-01 12:25:25.000 2,051307E+09    50000
2011-01-01 12:26:27.000 2,140614E+09    100000
2011-01-01 12:27:03.000 1,074146E+09    50000
```

...
I want to sum the recharged_money of each client and make groups of 5 days from the last to the first charge date.

So i pick the last date and sum all the recarged_money until 5 days before, and more 5 .. and so on. How can i accomplish that?

Ty in advanced,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help, if I haven't missed anything:

```
WITH marked AS (
  SELECT
    DATE_TIME,
    RECHARGED_MONEY,
    dategroup = DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE_TIME, MAX(DATE_TIME) OVER ()) / 5
  FROM RECHARGES
)
SELECT
  DATE_TIME       = MAX(DATE_TIME),
  RECHARGED_MONEY = SUM(RECHARGED_MONEY)
FROM marked
GROUP BY
  dategroup
ORDER BY
  DATE_TIME
```